# Ansible - Try to get a file on multiple url and fail only if all url have been called and file has not been found

Tags: ansible

I have a file that could be located on 1 of 3 urls, but not in the two others

I would like to try to get the file on each url:

- Sucess if the file is found during one of the iterations
- Fail if it's the end of the loop and the file has not been found

I have tried this :

```
  - name : Try to get the file
    uri:
      url: "{{ item }}"
      return_content: yes
      status_code:
        - 200
        - 404
    register: module_result
    with_items:
      - http://url_1/file.txt
      - http://url_2/file.txt
      - http://url_3/file.txt
    when: module_result is not defined or module_result.status == 404
```

But there is some not handled cases:

- Other http code than 200 or 404 is returned
- The last iteration return 404 the task and  should fail.

So my questions are :

- Is there a way to handle all HTTP returned code without writing all existing codes in `status_code`?
- How to fail the task when the last iteration doesn't return HTTP 200?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- name: Try to get the file
  uri:
    url: "{{ item }}"
    return_content: yes
  register: module_result
  with_items:
    - http://url_1/file.txt
    - http://url_2/file.txt
    - http://url_3/file.txt
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Register if there was any 200 status code
  set_fact:
    existing_file: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ module_result.results }}"
  when: item.status is defined and item.status == 200

- name: Fail if no 200 status code received
  fail:
    msg: No such file
  when: existing_file is not defined

- name: Display file content
  debug:
    msg: "{{ existing_file.content }}"
```

1. Loop over all URLs without failing at all
2. Loop over results and set `existing_file` variable only if result with 200 status code was found
3. Fail if `existing_file` is not defined
4. If not failed then your file content is in `existing_file.content` (and in this example will be displayed with `debug`)

Comment: Your solution seams to solve my first question. Thank you  

But in your second task, module_result doesn't have status field, but `result` field with all iterations results.  

"module_result": {
  "results": [{
          "item": "http://url_1/file.txt",
          "status": 404,
      },{
          "item": "http://url_2/file.txt",
          "status": 404,
      },{
          "content": "The content of my file",
          "item": "http://url_3/file.txt",
          "status": 200,
      }]
}

`

Comment: Sorry... i forgot about loop. I've corrected myself already. Try again.

Comment: It works better and better. Thank you!
The new problem is that when the first url returns the file, then the return HTTP code is not evaluated for the others.

I suggest adding to the condition "when: item.status is defined and item.status == 200" on Task: Register if there was any 200 statys code

Comment: I wasn't aware you need all files but there is no need for additional conditional. Just use `module_result.results[index].content` where `module_result.results[index].status == 200` as additional step. Of course `index` is number from 0 to end of your list.

Comment: Actually I don't need all the files. Only one of the 3 url returns the file sought, but I don't know which one.
If the file is in the first url, Ansible evaluates the HTTP code and adds the content to `existing_file` var.
However it will continue to iterate over the second url. 
But in the previous task, the second url was skipped and therefore has no HTTP code value and not "status" attribut. 
So during the evaluation, Ansible says that it doesn't know "status" in "item.status == 200"

Comment: Not enought reputation for +1, but thank's for your help. It works perfectly